What are all the evidences that may suggest Doyakonga is Minase?
A few months ago, some people observed that the infamous Twitter account Doyakonga is probably Minase Inorin, the well-known seiyuu who dubbed Rem from Re:Zero in Japanese. As someone who can't read Japanese, I found those Japanese blogs on this matter not of much help.
What are all the arguments, strong or weak, for this statement? Please be as comprehensive and detailed as possible.

Anime Hunch and Fiction Horizon have both posted English-language articles on the controversy. Summarising their contents, the evidence suggesting Minase ran the Doyakonga account appears to be the following:

On 3 April 2024, Minase quote-tweeted someone who had posted photos of her without permission, calling them "An idiot who can't read Minase's warning". The tweet was criticized for its tone and swiftly deleted, with Minase's representatives later tweeting on her behalf to claim her account had been hacked. Doyakonga was known to have made similar tweets in the past towards people who posted Minase's photos without permission, leading to speculation that Minase meant to post the tweet on Doyakonga but tweeted it to her main account by mistake.
At the same time, the Doyakonga account was deactivated. Many believe that if the account really was run by a fan of Minase's, it would have stuck around to defend her - the timing of the deletion instead implies that Minase knew she'd been rumbled and deleted the account to hide the evidence.
Doyakonga "was known for being extremely knowledgeable about Minase and getting its hands on unreleased information about the voice actress" - I'm unsure what that "unreleased information" was exactly, but obviously the person who would have the greatest access to such information would be Minase herself.
The account "consistently praised" several voice actresses that Minase had collaborated with in the past (such as Aoi Yuki and Saori Hayami) while making defamatory accusations towards VAs who had not (such as Yui Ogura and Maaya Uchida).
Doyakonga's writing style was very similar to Minase's, and their profiles listed many of the same interests and hobbies.
When Minase performs live shows, her fan club restricts attendance to only one performance per person, yet Doyakonga was able to attend several performances, implying they were not an ordinary fan.


I heard that Doyakonga's posting times never overlap with Inorin's working times. Kinda like how L deduced Kira was a student in Death Note.
